# PHP как парсить сайты где требуется ssl сертификат и шифрование?

Tags: php, request

Есть сайт [https://мвд.рф/wanted](https://xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai/wanted). При его парсинге на python все нормально, но при парсинге на php при использовании `file_get_contents()` такая ошибка:

```
SSL: Success in /home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85 Warning: 
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in 
/home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85 Warning: file_get_contents(xn-- 
b1aew.xn--p1ai/wanted): failed to open stream: operation failed in 
/home/runner/Php/main.php on line 85
```

А при использовании curl - такая ошибка:

```
OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL 
in connection to xn--b1aew.xn--p1ai:443.
```

Подскажите любые, желательно простые, способы получить нормальный ответ (200) от сайта.

Comment: Попробуй использовать curl.... при этом для курла надо использовать доп опции `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`   ..... возможно ещё `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`

Comment: можно через `file_get_contents` попробовать вот так сделать:  `$opt=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
$response = file_get_contents("https://xxx", false, stream_context_create($opt));`

Comment: Спасибо оба варианта пробовал не помогло.

Comment: Какая версия PHP хоть?

Comment: Версия PHP 7.4.21